# Angular 2 Dynamic form with ngModel

Tags: angular

I am trying to create dynamic form & till now everything is working fine, problem I am getting is with ngModel, currently I have json like this:

```
this.value= {
    phone: [
        {
            type: mobile,
            number: '123'
        }, 
        {
            type: landline,
            number: '321'
        }
    ], 
    email: [
        {
            type: work,
            number: 'xyz'
        }, 
        {
            type: personal,
            number: 'zyx'
        }
    ]
}
```

My form structure is stored in `this.fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure`, so this stores structure for phone & email like:

```
this.fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure = {
    'phone': {
        'type': 'text',
        'label': 'Phone number',
        'key': 'phone',
        'binding_key': 'number',
        'value': ''
    },
    'email': {
        'type': 'email',
        'label': 'Email',
        'key': 'email',
        'binding_key': 'address',
        'value': '',
        'validation': {
            'pattern': ''
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my component which have form element & that will be responsible to edit/add value for phone / email:

```
<input class="form-control"
    *ngIf="['text', 'email'].indexOf(fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure[field].type) != -1" 
    [formControlName]="fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure[field].key" 
    [id]="fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure[field].key" 
    [type]="fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure[field].type"
    [placeholder]="fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure[field].label"
    [(ngModel)]="valueModel"
    [ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }">
```

And the parent component is iterating through above template like:

```
<div
    *ngFor="let field of fieldPermission.structureList">
    <div class="form-field-block" 
        *ngFor="let value of data[field]; let i = index; ">
        <form-base
            [valueModel]="value[fieldPermission.fieldFormStructure[field].binding_key]"
            [field]="field"
            [form]="form"
            [index]="i"></form-base>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this works fine when `this.value.phone` has only one value, but breaks when have more than one like right now, it gives this error: `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '123'. Current value: '321'`. So I thought I can solve this by adding `[ngModelOptions]="{ standalone : true }"` but this gives another error which is: `Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'`

*Sorry guys it would be difficult to show running code in plunker*

Comment: ngModel and model driven forms do not really play well together. Use the form control to set the values instead...

Comment: Check out [ng-formly](https://github.com/formly-js/ng-formly). I used [angular-formly](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly) for creating dynamic forms in AngularJs and it was fine. I guess is the thing that you desire, configuring forms using a JSON.